# Whats wrong with my switch statment?

Tags: java, android

I made this switch statment and when i press the button line that part works when i press enter once that works but when i press it again it doesnt Why?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutPutConversion Out = new OutPutConversion();
    DrawingTools AddL = new DrawingTools();
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CL);
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    int n = 0;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.LineVL:
        info.setText("Enter x,y,z For Point 1");
        break;
    case R.id.Enter:
        switch (n) {
        case (0):
            String Input1 = cl.getText().toString();
            AddL.AddLine(Input1);
            info.setText("Enter x,y,z For Point 2");
            n++;
            break;
        case (1):
            String Input2 = cl.getText().toString();
            AddL.AddLine(Input2);
            info.setText("Press Enter Again TO See Results");
            n++;
            break;
        case (2):
            n = 0;
            Out.Out();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: remove `int n=0;` outside function. As of now each time, value is re-set to 0.

Comment: you never change the value of `n`!

Comment: ahh ok that makes since thank you guys!

Comment: @Ashish Patil: you should turn your comment into an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `int n=0;` outside function. As of now each time, value is re-set to 0.

Comment: How would I create n so it gets updated?

Comment: create as object variable instead of method field.